# ¿Cómo quitar elementos o comentar elementos con jQuery?

Tags: jquery

El problema de añadir `plugin` o **URLs** de vídeos a mi pagina web es que los contenidos de los videos de la **URLs** o el **Plugins** genera enlaces externos a otro sitio web, entonces quería tratar de ver si con `jQuery` se podría evitar que estos enlaces se generen.

La idea es comentar los enlaces `<!-- -->` o quitarlos pero no todos, se podría crear una condición que todo enlace que no tenga el `id="nobloquear"` se comente o quitarlos mediante **jQuery**

> No soy muy experto en **jQuery** conocimientos muy básicos.

Lo unico que e logrado es conseguir eliminar un contenido específico del documento de la página es decir el contenido de la clase `.delete` elimina solo si existe una palabra o un contenido específico en este ejemplo será la palabra **hello**.

```js
 $( ".delete" ).remove( ":contains('Hello')" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div>
     <div class="delete">Hello</div>
     <div class="delete">No se elimina porque este div no existe la palabra hola en inglés, a pesar de ser la misma clase .delete</div>
  </div>
```

> Realmente este ejemplo no se profundiza a mi idea que es eliminar o comentar los enlaces que no tenga la **class:** `class="nobloquear"`

Me podrian ayudar

Comment: Por favor, añade más información a la pregunta: ¿qué plugin estás usando?¿cómo es tu código? (crea un [mcve]) ¿cuál es el código de los enlaces que quieres quitar?

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro Respondiendo la pregunta: ¿cuál es el código de los enlaces que quieres quitar? Realmente no sabría porque la **Urls** del **streaming** de video o **plugins** genera enlace de publicidad enlaces externos a otros sitio web, entonces una idea que se me ocurrió es comentar o eliminar todo enlace que no tenga la clase `class="nobloquear"` pienso que sería una solución.

Comment: @J.Mick ¿qué plugin estás usando?

Comment: Y como sugerencia: revisa las condiciones de uso del plugin, normalmente si ponen publicidad es porque estás usando una versión gratuita de un servicio, esconder la publicidad o el nombre del plugin seguramente vaya contra las condiciones de uso y puede acabar con tu cuenta cancelada

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No puede haber más de un elemento con un id, usemos la clase `nobloquear` para las excepciones.

**Borrar todos los `<a>` que no tengan una clase:**

```js
$('a').not('.nobloquear').remove();
```

```js
$(function() { //document ready
    $('#borrar').on('click', function(e){ //click en botón
        //borrar todos los enlaces excepto los de clase 'nobloquear'
        $('a').not('.nobloquear').remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery --><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="nobloquear" href="#url">Enlace 1</a><br>
<a href="#url">Enlace para borrar 1</a><br>
<a class="nobloquear" href="#url">Enlace 2</a><br>
<a href="#url">Enlace para borrar 2</a><br>
<a class="nobloquear" href="#url">Enlace 3</a><br>
<a href="#url">Enlace para borrar 3</a><br>
<input type="button" id="borrar" value="Borrar enlaces">
```

**Comentar todos los `<a>` que no tengan una clase:**

No tiene mucho sentido de esta forma, los comentarios son parte del HTML, no del DOM. Se haría:

```js
$('a').not('.nobloquear').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith('<!-- ' + $(this)[0].outerHTML + ' -->');
});
```

```js
$(function() { //document ready
    $('#borrar').on('click', function(e){ //click en botón
        //comentar todos los enlaces excepto los de clase 'nobloquear'
        $('a').not('.nobloquear').each(function(){
            $(this).replaceWith('<!-- ' + $(this)[0].outerHTML + ' -->');
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery --><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="nobloquear" href="#url">Enlace 1</a><br>
<a href="#url">Enlace para borrar 1</a><br>
<a class="nobloquear" href="#url">Enlace 2</a><br>
<a href="#url">Enlace para borrar 2</a><br>
<a class="nobloquear" href="#url">Enlace 3</a><br>
<a href="#url">Enlace para borrar 3</a><br>
<a class="nobloquear" href="#url">Enlace 4</a><br>
<a href="#url">Enlace para borrar 4</a><br>
<input type="button" id="borrar" value="Comentar enlaces">
```

Comment: Hola @Mariano perfecto es justo lo que tenía en mente, pero lo deseado es que la acción se ejecute automáticamente por sí sola, en vez de los botones `comentar enlaces` y `borrar enlace` saludos.

Comment: he editado mi pregunta? Para que se ejecute la acción automáticamente debo quitar esto: `$('#borrar').on('click', function(e){ //click en botón });` verdad? Así se eliminaría la acción del botón estoy en lo correcto.

Comment: @J.Mick - Gracias por editar la pregunta... Exacto. El código que está en la parte principal de la respuesta es lo que elimina/comenta los enlaces... Probablemente te convenga dejarlo dentro de `$(function() {` ... `});` para que se ejecute sólo cuando se terminó de cargar la página.